# Why is it called Marshal.AllocHGlobal if it allocates on the local heap?

Tags: c#, winapi, memory-management, marshalling

From the MSDN documentation of [`Marshal.AllocHGlobal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bkh17.aspx):

> AllocHGlobal is one of two memory allocation methods in the Marshal class. This method exposes the Win32 LocalAlloc function from Kernel32.dll.

<strike>Considering there's a GlobalAlloc API which allocates memory on the *global* heap, rather than the *local* heap,</strike> isn't this method's name rather misleading?

Was there a reason for naming it `AllocHGlobal`, rather than `AllocHLocal`?

**Update:** Simon points out in the comments that there's no such thing as a global heap in Windows any more, and the `GlobalAlloc` and `LocalAlloc` APIs remained for legacy purposes only. These days, the `GlobalAlloc` API is nothing morethan a wrapper for `LocalAlloc`.

This explains why the API doesn't call `GlobalAlloc` at all, but it doesn't explain why the API was named `AllocHGlobal` when it doesn't (can't) use a global heap, nor does it even call `GlobalAlloc`. The naming cannot possibly be for legacy reasons, because it wasn't introduced until .NET 2.0, way after 16-bit support was dropped. So, the question remains: why is `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` so misleadingly named?

Comment: Fyi, both LocalAlloc and GlobalAlloc is documented with "Windows memory management does not provide a separate local heap and global heap. Therefore, the LocalAlloc and GlobalAlloc functions are essentially the same."

Comment: Interesting. I'm actually surprised that I did not know that - normally I'm pretty up to date on Windows memory management. I guess it makes sense though, especially in multiprocessor environments. Shared memory is notoriously unstable and awkward.

Comment: They were different in 16-bit Windows, when memory could be easily shared between tasks.

Comment: Since .NET didn't exist back in ye olde 16-bit days, this still doesn't explain why it's called `AllocHGlobal` rather than `AllocHLocal`.

Comment: Most "legacy" API calls know it as an `HGlobal` don't thay? Maybe it was to reduce confusion.

Comment: In Windows 7 at the very least, the implementation of `Local*` an `Global*` is merged almost fully (perhaps just argument checks are still separate). Both `LocalAlloc` and `GlobalAlloc` redirect to `_RtlAllocateHeap`, and `LocalFree` is full alias for `GlobalFree`. This might be insufficient reason to confuse API naming on the docs, but at least the confusion does not make much of a difference anymore.

Comment: @RomanR. Indeed. The main confusion here is why it was named `AllocHGlobal` in .NET at all. It's not a global heap allocation, it doesn't call `GlobalAlloc` - it makes no sense for it to be named as it is (as far as I can see).

Comment: @arx Post that as an answer, it seems to be correct.

Comment: Part of the documentation says "it's the same", but the **very same page** still says "It is not safe to free memory allocated with `GlobalAlloc` using `LocalFree`." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you're doing data transfer between apps using drag and drop or over the clipboard. To populate the [`STGMEDIUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683812%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure you need an `HGLOBAL`. So you call `AllocHGlobal`. Hence the name.

The main use for this function is to interop with APIs that want an `HGLOBAL`. It would be confusing if it was called anything else because when you wanted an `HGLOBAL` you'd have to find some documentation to tell you that `AllocAnythingElse` produced a value you could use as an `HGLOBAL`.

Comment: It might be worth adding that it used to be the case that LocalAlloc was more efficient in the immediate post-Win16 era (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/01/250610.aspx); hence why AllocHGlobal calls LocalAlloc and not GlobalAlloc even though in Win32 they are essentially equivalent - because in the early Win32 era LocalAlloc superseded GlobalAlloc for general purpose usage.

Comment: Some of the security function examples seem to mix both HeapAlloc and LocalAlloc which seems strange, why aren't they exclusively using HeapAlloc?

Comment: @arx: I agree with your answer right up to the point of "So you call `AllocHGlobal`."  Like you said, `STGMEDIUM` structure needs an `HGLOBAL`.  **But `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` does not give you an `HGLOBAL`!** (Even accounting for the fact that `LocalAlloc` and `GlobalAlloc` are the same and you could get an `HGLOBAL` from `LocalAlloc`, `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` passes the `GMEM_FIXED` flag, which means the result isn't an `HGLOBAL` after all.)

Comment: The entire rest of the answer is therefore totally wrong.  You can't use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` to interop with APIs that want an `HGLOBAL`.

Comment: @BenVoigt What API expects an HGLOBAL but demands that it is not fixed?

Comment: @arx: Your own example, `STGMEDIUM`.  When you pass `GMEM_FIXED` to `GlobalAlloc` or `LocalAlloc`, as `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` does, you get a pointer, as the documentation says:  "
`GMEM_FIXED
0x0000`

Allocates fixed memory. The return value is a pointer."  For use with `STGMEDIUM`, you need to use the flag `GMEM_MOVEABLE` instead, so you get an actual `HGLOBAL`.

Comment: See here: ["`TYMED_HGLOBAL`
    The storage medium is a global memory handle (`HGLOBAL`). Allocate the global handle with the `GMEM_MOVEABLE` flag."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691227.aspx)  You simply can't do that with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, it never passes the `GMEM_MOVEABLE` flag to get an `HGLOBAL`, it only ever gets a pointer.

Comment: In summary, you said: "To populate the STGMEDIUM structure you need an HGLOBAL. So you call AllocHGlobal."  In reality: "To populate the STGMEDIUM structure you need an HGLOBAL allocated using GMEM_MOVEABLE.  You can't get that from AllocHGlobal."

Comment: @BenVoigt Fair enough.  If I don't think of a way of fixing this answer I'll delete it.

Comment: Well? The answer is both still here and non-fixed (unlike the value returned by AllocHGlobal).

Comment: 2021, and this was never edited and never deleted. (For perspective, this answer was posted in 2012)

Answer (score 3):

This goes back to the olden days of Windows version 3.  Back then there was a notion of a "default heap", the GlobalAlloc() api function allocated from it.  Memory allocated from that heap could be shared between all processes.

That changed in the 32-bit version of Windows, processes can no longer share memory through a heap.  Which made the terms "global heap" and "local heap" meaningless.  There is still a notion of a default heap, the "process heap".  GlobalAlloc() now allocates from that heap.  But it can't be shared across process boundaries.  The actual implementation of GlobalAlloc, and of Marshal.AllocHGlobal, uses the LocalAlloc() api function.  Another Windows 3 holdover, somewhat more suitably named for what happens these days.  It in turn uses HeapAlloc() with GetProcessHeap() on 32-bit Windows.

Agreeing on the heap to use is a significant interop concern.  This very often goes wrong in poorly written C code that you pinvoke.  Any such code that returns a pointer to allocated memory that needs to be released by the caller often fails due to memory leaks or access violations.  Such C code allocates from its own heap with the malloc() function.  Which is a private heap created by the C runtime library.  You have no hope of releasing such memory, you don't know what heap was used and have no way to obtain the handle to the CRT heap.

This can only come to a good end when the C code uses a well-known heap.  Like the process heap.  Or CoTaskMemAlloc(), used by COM code.  The other one in the Marshal class.  Note that the pinvoke marshaller always releases memory when necessary with CoTaskMemFree().  That's a kaboom on Vista and up if that memory wasn't allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc(), a silent leak on XP.

Comment: I agree with and understand everything you've said here, but it doesn't answer my question. Why was the .NET API called `AllocHGlobal` rather than `AllocHLocal`, when it doesn't call `GlobalAlloc` at all? Having it only use the local heap makes perfect sense, because there isn't a global heap any more, but if the global heap didn't exist at all back when .NET 2.0 came out (which is when `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` was introduced), why the heck was it named so misleadingly?

Comment: Sigh.  What is "local" supposed to mean in this context?  When *any* code that runs in the process can access that heap.  If you can't live with this then send your feedback to connect.microsoft.com.  You'll have to give some pretty convincing arguments to get them to change the name, to put it mildly.

Comment: I'm not asking them to change it, I'm just questioning *why* they decided to name it after a deprecated API that isn't even called. Is it really so bad for me to be questioning a design decision that I don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603.aspx

A short part of it:

> Global and Local Memory Functions At first glance it appears that the
>   local and global memory management functions exist in Windows purely
>   for backward compatibility with Windows version 3.1. This may be true,
>   but the functions are managed as efficiently as the new heap functions
>   discussed below. In fact, porting an application from 16-bit Windows
>   does not necessarily include migrating from global and local memory
>   functions to heap memory functions. The global and local functions
>   offer the same basic capabilities (and then some) and are just as fast
>   to work with. If anything, they are probably more convenient to work
>   with because you do not have to keep track of a heap handle.
>
> Nonetheless, the implementation of these functions is not the same as
>   it was for 16-bit Windows. 16-bit Windows had a global heap, and each
>   application had a local heap. Those two heap managers implemented the
>   global and local functions. Allocating memory via GlobalAlloc meant
>   retrieving a chunk of memory from the global heap, while LocalAlloc
>   allocated memory from the local heap. Windows now has a single heap
>   for both types of functions—the default heap described above.
>
> Now you're probably wondering if there is any difference between the
>   local and global functions themselves. Well, the answer is no, they
>   are now the same. In fact, they are interchangeable. Memory allocated
>   via a call to LocalAlloc can be reallocated with GlobalReAlloc and
>   then locked by LocalLock. The following table lists the global and
>   local functions now available.
>
> It seems redundant to have two sets of functions that perform exactly
>   the same, but that's where the backward compatibility comes in.
>   Whether you used the global or local functions in a 16-bit Windows
>   application before doesn't matter now—they are equally efficient.

etc...

Also memory was really expensive back in the days. Also have a look at the PostScript Language Reference Manual which might give you a good insight on usage of local/global memory.

Comment: And yet, the documentation for LocalFree() says the exact opposite: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalfree `It is not safe to free memory allocated with LocalAlloc.`