# PostScript memory management implementation for local and global

Tags: c#, memory-management, postscript

In PostScript you have VM to store the values of composite objects.
They can be stored in local or global VM depending on the VM allocation mode of the interpreter.

I'm working on an interpreter in C# (a bit similar to the JAVA) language. And I can't figure out how to represent local and global VM.

Let's say I have an object:

```
public class StringObj : Composite {
 public string Data { get;set; }
}
```

The *Data* property (value of StringObj) is stored either in local or global VM. But how could this be presented in C# (or Java).

C# itself already has memory management itself (stack/heap/...) but these are the internals of the language and .NET framework, which I can't control.

Should I need to create an own memory structure? If so, how would/could that be represented?
Or would it be ok to just store a *bool* property on each Composite object to know if it is local or global, something like this:

```
public class StringObj : Composite {
 public string Data { get;set; }
 public bool IsGlobal { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

Maybe if I know how the "save" operator works, I might better understand how to implement the memory management.

**What exactly does the "save" operator save?**

*"creates a snapshot of the current state of virtual memory"*

From reading the restore operator I think it stores this:

- The array packing mode (packing)
- VM allocation mode (boolean)
- object output format (?)
- user interpreter parameters (?)
- saves a copy of the current graphics state on the graphics state stack

What else does it save? as the definition of "current state of virtual memory" is not quite good defined.

Should I also check every object on the stack to verify if it is composite or not and save the value of the object on the stack? or are stacks/dictionaries untouched? or..?

Comment: interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778435/why-is-it-called-marshal-allochglobal-if-it-allocates-on-the-local-heap

Comment: you need to understand the behavior of these types of allocation. They are `type 1` and `type 2`. Dont try to map to c# or java constructs ('global' , 'local', 'heap', ....). Simply think, 'i need to store A in such a way that its does x,y and z' (has a specific scope, lifetime, size,...)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question anyone else can answer for you, if you are intent on writing your own PostScript interpreter.

You will need to fully understand the memory management of PostScript objects, and their lifetime, and design your own memory management around that. I think it very unlikely that you can get away **without** designing your own memory structure(s), I've certainly never seen a PostScript interpreter which didn't.

Again I can't answer a vague question like "how would/could that be represented?", that's much too general. There are many ways you could design a PostScript memory manager, the choice is entirely yours. If memory management interests you then presumably you will have a preferred approach, if it doesn't then stick with something simple, just make sure it covers all the basics.

By the way, is there a reason you are writing your own interpreter, other than personal satisfaction ? The general consensus is that its more than 5 man year work to implement a PostScript interpreter (potentially less if you use a pre-existing graphics library for rendering, assuming you have a PostScript-compatible one). That seems like a lot of work for a 30+ year old language that is not in wide usage.

Regarding save:

save saves, well, everything.... Just like the sentence you quoted, a save is a mark that you can later return to, and encapsulates everything in the PostScript VM.

I think you've missed the fact that I can make changes to a composite object, and those changes are subject to save and restore.

Try this:

```
%!
/mydict <</Test (this is a string)>> def

save
mydict /Test (This is not a string) put

mydict /Test get == flush
restore
mydict /Test get == flush
```

Notice that the content of the dictionary changes after the restore.

One interpreter I knew of used save as,essentially, a 'high water mark', combined with a copy-on-write architecture. If you performed an operation on an existing composite object which was below a save mark, then the object was copied, and the alteration made to the copy. Then a restore simply freed everything back to the last save mark. However details of implementation are not specified, provided the interpreter behaves correctly you can do anything you like.

Note that objects in **global** VM are not subject to save and restore. You also need to be careful around the stack contents when doing a restore, to ensure that objects on the stack wouldn't be discarded, this triggers an invalidrestore error.

Note 2, the job server loop save and restore **will** affect global VM.....

Comment: a hobby project gone crazy and a good interest in these things :-). It would be great if advantage could be taken from the C# language to manage local/global, looking for info on how other projects tackle the local/global VM issue. As I've not seen many projects taking care of it.

Comment: Well there are not (these days) so many PostScript interpreters around. Ghostscript is available for perusal, and "luser droog" has his own xpost here https://github.com/luser-dr00g/xpost Ghostscript wraps up the type, attributes and vm allocation in a single unsigned short (see psi/iref.h). I've seen other systems.

Comment: I've updated the question to trying to better understand the save operator. This might give me better insights but what exactly does save save? :-)